# A stronger version of the monotone convergence theorem

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Definition: Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. We say that $\{a_n\}$ is **"eventually-increasing"** iff there exists $N\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $\{a_{i+N}\}_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ is increasing.

**Question:** Let $(X,\scr{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ be a sequence of measurable functions $(f_n:X\rightarrow [0,\infty[$). Assume further that $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise and that for every $x\in X$ the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ is "eventually-increasing". Does it follow that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_Xf_n d\mu=\int_Xfd\mu$$
I  made a few trials to prove it but didn't succeed. However, I also suspect the existence of a counterexample.

Thank you

Comment: $f_n=n\cdot\chi_{[0,1/n]}$?

Comment: By increasing, do you mean strictly increasing?

Comment: @neelp no just increasing .

Comment: @DavidMitra OK, thanks

Comment: Even if you asked for eventually strictly increasing you would have counter examples. They're not hard to find.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I know. I was just telling neelp what I had in mind when I said "increasing"

Comment: @Amr However, I must point out that is the whole sequence of functions is eventually increasing the result is true. That is, if there is some $N$ --not depending on $x$-- such that $\{f_{n+N}\}$ is increasing. This is trivial from Lebesgue's Monotonous convergence theorem.

Comment: @JouseTonelli-Cueto Thanks I already know that

Comment: @DavidMitra I do not see how $f_n=n\cdot\chi_{0,1/n}$ is eventually increasing.

Comment: @Ton For any $x\ne0$, $f_n(x)$ is eventually $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. Consider $f_n(x)=1$ for $x\in[n,n+1]$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f_n\to f:=0$, $f_n(x)=0$ for $x<n$, $\int f_n=1$ and $\int f=0$.

Comment: That's essentially the example. Good job! +1

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Right. Thanks sranthrop